# PhpMyAdmin and MySQL Error #2006 can't login in a SSL connection

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, phpmyadmin

I have been looking on the web how to solve this problem, but in every thread about this error there is a solution that says to add in `etc/my.cnf max_allowed_packet` and `wait_timeout.` I have tried both and nothing happens. Another solution is to disable SSL connection between MySQL and PhpMyAdmin in config.inc.php `($cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true)`, I tried this and it worked, I was able to login and see my tables, but I really need this connection to be secure. I recently updated my PHP to 5.5 and I have MySQL 5.5

I hope someone can help me with this please. I have tried everything and nothing works with SSL enabled in PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Those variables would not apply to SSL troubleshooting.  Remove the 3rd party code (phpmyadmin is not part of MySQL) from the mix of things to troubleshoot, by first verifying that you can connect to the server, using your cert, key, and ca file, with the official `mysql` command line client.  Only once you've confirmed that this is working should you then try connecting with PMA or anything else using SSL.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: Sorry that I'm late but @Michael-sqlbot was right, I was getting confused but everything is fine now, thank you.